# AddressOf operator in C

Tags: c, operating-system

The AddressOf operator returns the address of the associated variable. Is the returned address "Logical address" or "Physical address" of the variable?

Comment: It's the logical address; the o/s conceals the physical address from you.

Answer (score 0):

It would return the logical address.